# A combination for monitoring system for container (Grafana+Heapster+InfluxDB+cAdvisor) based on baremetal

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

Expert

I have a question related monitoring system for container.
Below picture has my thinking for monitoring.

[image]

I'd like to run monitoring combination(Grafana,Heapster,InfluxDB,cAdvisor) on baremetal as a daemon process instead of running in containers.
When i configure those 4 units...i got the error below.
It might be comes out from linking influxdb to Heapster (ex:--sink)

Below is my commands to run heapster

```
"./heapster --source=cadvisor:external?cadvisorPort=8081 --sink=influxdb:http://192.168.56.20:8086/db=k8s&user=root&pw=root"
```

Then I get following message

> driver.go:326 Database creation failed : Server returned (404): 404
>   page not found

What symptom it is?
Someone if have a solution? let me get an advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of influxdb and heapster are you using? I found a [heapster github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/619) with the same symptom, caused by a heapster version which doesn't support a specific influxdb version. By the way, do you use kubernetes to run the containers and why do you want to run the monitoring system as daemon processes?

Comment: Influxdb 0.9.4, heapster 0.18.2... the reason is to just make standalone monitoring system which is no dependency with docker and kubernetes. which version do i need to use?

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/pull/548) updated heapster to support influxdb 0.9.4. I don't see it included in any release tags, so you may need to use HEAD. As for the standalone monitoring system, you will still need to deal with deploying and upgrading it yourself? How do you plan to do it? Kubernetes+a container runtime could make this easier...

Comment: i agree with you on the management aspect. plan to use the form of container for monitoring.